# kubernetes not access by NodePort

Tags: kubernetes

After deploy [Guestbook example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/guestbook), I'm stuck in the problem that I can't access by NodeIP:NodePort. Does anybody meet the same problem and have fixed? Any help is welcome.

#### Description

not access via **curl [NodeIP]:[NodePort]**, access via endpoints in busybox Pod.

- result of cmd `netstat -ntpl|grep 30061` 

  `tcp6       0      0 :::30061                :::*                    LISTEN      14790/kube-proxy`
- result of cmd `curl 127.0.0.1:30061 -v`

  `About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 30061 (#0)
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connection refused
  Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:30061; Connection refused
  Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:30061; Connection refused`

#### cluser info

- Machine: 3 * CentOS VM
- kubernetes Version

  `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"d33fd89e399396658aed4e48dfe7d5d8d50ac6e8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-26T17:08:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
  Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"d33fd89e399396658aed4e48dfe7d5d8d50ac6e8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-26T17:08:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`
- result of cmd `kubectl get endpoints`

  `NAME           ENDPOINTS                           AGE
  frontend       172.17.81.4:8020                    2d
  kubernetes     10.202.130.190:6443                 6d
  redis-master   172.17.81.2:6379                    2d
  redis-slave    172.17.50.5:6379,172.17.81.3:6379   2d`
- result of cmd `kubectl get service`

  `NAME           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
  frontend       10.254.104.214   <nodes>       80:30061/TCP                 2d
  kubernetes     10.254.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      6d
  nginxsvc       10.254.69.133    <nodes>       80:32196/TCP,443:30793/TCP   4d
  redis-master   10.254.85.103    <none>        6379/TCP                     2d
  redis-slave    10.254.137.163   <none>        6379/TCP                     2d`
- the port config of service frontend

`ports:
  - port: 80
    nodePort: 30061
    targetPort: 8020
  selector:
    app: guestbook
    ti`

Answer (score -1):

> If you want to access the guestbook **from outside of the cluster**, add `type: NodePort` to the frontend Service spec field.
>
> Then you can access the guestbook with `<NodeIP>:NodePort` **from outside of the cluster**.
>
> **On cloud providers which support external load balancers**, adding `type: LoadBalancer` to the front end Service spec field will provision a load balancer for your Service.

---

Seems that you are accessing it from your localhost, then you should run

`kubectl cluster-info` then run

`curl <kubernets_master_ip>:30061`

Comment: Actually, I have tried the cmd, then I find it can't be access via **Cluster virtualIP**. It will hang executing the cmd `curl 10.254.104.214:80`.

Comment: Could you try with loadbalancer then.

Comment: The machine isn't cloud machine. I try to expose redis master service to nodePort 30001. The redis service can be access using `redis-cli -h localhost -p 30001`. Is it strange?

Comment: I tried to using minikube,

`NAME              CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
frontend          10.0.0.202   <pending>     80:32199/TCP     37m`


then,

`minikute ssh`
Run

`curl 10.0.0.202:80`
it's work for me.

Comment: Are you running it from cluster node?

Comment: Yes, the goal is cluster deploy. I will try dns addon later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147029/discussion-between-onebraveman-and-deepak).

Comment: Hey, got it

Run 
`kubectl cluster-info`

then try `curl <kubernets_master_ip>:30061`

Comment: The output is  `Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080`.